# Multiple TextViews Added in Loop onClick Unexpected Behavior

Tags: android, onclick, textview

I have two RelativeLayouts that I am programmatically adding TextViews to from an ArrayList with the intent that, based on the TextView clicked, I can index back into the original ArrayList. For my trivial code example, I'm arbitrarily splitting the items into the two RelativeLayouts.

The code works as expected when the first TextView is clicked. The dialog shows up displaying the correct word and index. However, after closing the dialog, if a different TextView is clicked, the word and index (testWord and testID in my code example) are not updated and only the first TextView's information is displayed. It seems that onClick is only being called on the first click.

Here is an example Java class (I apologize for any formatting errors, it's my first time posting here):

```
package com.test.test;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AndTestActivity extends Activity {
    private final int DIALOG_CASE_ITEM_SELECT=0,CURR_ID=128,P_ID=256,P_HR=512,C_HR=1024;
    private final String TEST="This is a test. Only a test.";
    private int numPast,testID;
    private String testWord;
    private ArrayList<String> test; 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Scanner s=new Scanner(TEST);
        test=new ArrayList<String>();
        while(s.hasNext()){
            test.add(s.next());
        }
        int currID=CURR_ID,pID=P_ID,pHrID=P_HR,cHrID=C_HR,tempLen=3;        
        numPast=0;
        RelativeLayout rlP=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.caseItemListPastLayout);
        RelativeLayout rlC=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.caseItemListCurrLayout);
        for(int x=0;x<test.size();x++){                                 
            if(x>tempLen){                      
                addToRL(test.get(x),true,rlC,currID,cHrID);
                currID++;
                cHrID++;
            }else{              
                numPast++;
                    addToRL(test.get(x),false,rlP,pID,pHrID);
                pID++;
                pHrID++;
            }       
        }       
    }

    private void addToRL(String sb, boolean current,RelativeLayout rl,int id,int hrID){
        TextView citv=new TextView(this);
        citv.setText((CharSequence)sb);
        citv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        citv.setTextSize(15);
        citv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        citv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        if(current){
            citv.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);                 
        }else{
            citv.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
        citv.setPadding(20, 10, 20, 10);
        citv.setWidth((int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 360, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
        citv.setId(id);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams cilp=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        if(current&&id!=CURR_ID)cilp.addRule( RelativeLayout.BELOW, hrID-1);
        else{
            if(id!=P_ID)cilp.addRule( RelativeLayout.BELOW, hrID-1);
        }
        citv.setLayoutParams(cilp);
        citv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                TextView tv0=(TextView)v;
                int tvID=tv0.getId()-P_ID;
                if(tvID<0){
                    tvID=(tv0.getId()-CURR_ID)+numPast;
                }

                testID=tvID;
                testWord=test.get(testID);

                showDialog(DIALOG_CASE_ITEM_SELECT); 
            }
        });
        rl.addView(citv);                        
        View hr=new View(this);
        hr.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.background));
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams hrlp=new        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 5);
        hrlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,id);        
        hr.setLayoutParams(hrlp);
        hr.setId(hrID);
        rl.addView(hr);
    }

    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        Dialog dialog;
        AlertDialog.Builder builder;
        switch(id){
        case DIALOG_CASE_ITEM_SELECT:
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("word: "+testWord+" index: "+testID)
                   .setCancelable(true)
                   .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                           dialog.cancel();
                       }
                   });
            dialog = builder.create();
            break;
        default:
            dialog = null;
        }
        return dialog;
    }
}
```

Here is the associated XML for the layout (nothing special, but I thought I'd include it so there's a fully working example):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"     android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">       
    <ScrollView 
        android:id="@+id/caseItemCurrScroll"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/caseItemListCurrLayout"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content">
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/caseItemScrollSpacer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/caseItemCurrScroll"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:background="@color/background"/>
    <ScrollView 
        android:id="@+id/caseItemPastScroll"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/caseItemScrollSpacer"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/caseItemListPastLayout"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content">
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

That should be a fully "working" example, with the addition of

```
<color name="background">#3E3E3E</color>
```

in the strings.xml

Comment: "I apologize for any formatting errors, it's my first time posting here" Your code formatting is great. If you want to use code in the `middle` of a sentence use `.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onCreateDialog()` is only called once, while `onPrepareDialog()` is called each time the Dialog opens.

Override `onPrepareDialog()` and call `((AlertDialog) dialog).setMessage()` here.

Comment: Thank you! I was so focused on the TextView values I didn't think of the Dialog.